# How do I get visitor email addresses who visit my website?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website. We provide service with this website. When a customer visits my website I want to get their email address or contact information So that I can give them a reminder about my service.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can add a form using any one of countless plugins to collect an email address. If the question is can you get it automatically, without the user providing it, the answer is no — that would be a terrible security risk

Comment: The answer is no you can't. You can have them fill out a form....

Answer (score 0):

You can ask visitors to fill out a form giving you their information. There are many ways to do that in WordPress, starting with the built-in comment form. You can find all sorts of advice on that on the intertoobz.

Can you get that information automatically? No, no, a thousand times no. And even if you could and did the privacy (GDPR) authorities in Europe and other places would probably issue a warrant for your arrest. Privacy advocates really really don't like it when people gather information about site visitors without their consent.